# Как после отправки формы перенаправить пользователя на текущую страницу без зацикливания?

Tags: wordpress

пробую исправить так но все равно на главной оказываюсь

подскажите пожалуйста ,у меня есть форма в личном кабинете,но с нее бросает на главную

```
global $user_ID, $user_LK;
if($user_ID == $user_LK): ?>
<form method="POST" action="/" class="premium-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="premium-form_nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce("premium-form_nonce")?>"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Премеум" title="premium" style="background-color:#b93228;color:#fff;width: 90%;">
</form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

вот ее обработчик в function.php

```
 if (isset( $_POST['premium-form_nonce'])) {
      
        $user_ID = get_current_user_id();
        
     if( wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['premium-form_nonce'], 'premium-form_nonce' )  &&  rcl_get_user_rating($user_ID) > 100) {  
       
         $args = array(
          'rating_value' => -10,
          'object_author' => $user_ID
          );
    
         update_user_meta( $user_ID, 'premeum', 1);
         update_user_meta( $user_ID, 'premeum-time',current_time('timestamp', 1)); 

// тут редирект на текущюю
        global $wp;
        wp_redirect(home_url(add_query_arg(array($_GET), $wp->request)));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменить адрес в форме

изменить

```
<form method="POST" action="/" class="premium-form">
```

на

```
<form method="POST" action="" class="premium-form">
```

Также обработчик должен быть в хуке 'init'

```
add_action('init',  'processForm');

function processForm() {
    if (isset( $_POST['premium-form_nonce'])) {
      
        $user_ID = get_current_user_id();
        
     if( wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['premium-form_nonce'], 'premium-form_nonce' )  &&  rcl_get_user_rating($user_ID) > 100) {  
       
         $args = array(
          'rating_value' => -10,
          'object_author' => $user_ID
          );
    
         update_user_meta( $user_ID, 'premeum', 1);
         update_user_meta( $user_ID, 'premeum-time',current_time('timestamp', 1)); 

// тут редирект на текущюю
        global $wp;
        wp_redirect(home_url(add_query_arg(array($_GET), $wp->request)));
      }
    }
}
```